# how to handle clicks in a List View (with icons)?

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to implement a List View with icons within an Activity, but there are other widgets in this Activity - like buttons. This Activity has a layout file.

At first I saw this tutorial ( http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/ ), but realized that it was not what I needed.. because.. it extends Activity... to ListActivity. But I could not simply change my Activity to a ListActivity, because I had buttons and other things in it...

so I didn't understand how to implement it this way...

So instead implemented it using this tutorial...

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

which worked great until I realized that I don't know how to get at my clicks...

I put this code into my Activity...

```
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            //get selected items
            String selectedValue = Integer.toString(position);
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

... and at least it displays the # of the item selected in a Toast...

but I have no idea now how to share this selection with my Activity or any object that is related to my Activity...

is this a dead end? Is the "weather tutorial" listview for read-only purposes? and not for user-interaction?

Any suggestions appreciated. I would most like to just simply use the weather tutorial example if possible, since I already implemented it that way...

but if someone could explain the theory between the first tutorial's approach and how I would use my list view class than extends ListActivity within my main Activity (that contains buttons and other things), that would be great...

Answer (score 0):

Mostly item click listener in the listview is used to navigatue to another activity or display the information about the clicked item.

with position you can get clicked item from array or arraylist. corresponding to that item you can perform operations.

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton architecture

declare a static method in your activity like this for ex: "demoActivity"

```
public demoActivity extends Activity
{
private static demoActivity sInstance;

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
      sInstance=this;
     }

    public static demoActivity getInstance()
    {
         return sInstance;
    }
}
```

By using this instance you can just play with the activity.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```